# js adding and removing class dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im wanting to add and remove classes with Jquery, 80% all working except for it only happens once..
The other issue is when i remove a class it breaks the animation as-well.
So i am not too confident in Jquery and would like some assistance please.

```
$('.menu li').hover(function() {
     $('.menu li.active').removeClass('active');
     $(this).addClass('active');
     if ($('.menu li').hasClass('active')) {
         $('.menu').addClass("show_menu");  // simple 2 second animation css
         $(".menu").mouseleave(function(){                      
                $('.menu').addClass("hide_menu");  //simple 2 second animation css
                $('.menu li.active').removeClass('active');        
         });              
     }          
});
```

This works one time but when i choose another or the same `<menu li>` the animation to show menu doesn't work, also i tried removing class of `show_menu` but then the `hide_menu` animation will fail.

I put one together http://jsfiddle.net/mvMJ5/2/

Comment: Please add a http://jsfiddle.net demonstration of your problem.

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. You `addClass('active')` and then immediately check `hasClass('active')`. That test is unnecessary, it will never be false. You *just* added that class. You're also rebinding events inside event handlers, without ever unbinding events, which means you'll have the same event handler firing multiple times. You only need to bind events once to each element.

Comment: You use 'menu' a lot instead of '.menu' I think all your references to menu need the . (period) if you're referencing a class otherwise jquery will be looking for a 'menu' tag so I'm not entirely sure how this is working at all

Comment: Best practice would be to wrap it into a [jquery ready function](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) because it wait's for the DOM to load.

Comment: Try changing "menu" to ".menu" as jQuery uses "#" for ids and "." for classes when accessing elements.

Comment: i missed the .... i dont understand the down votes though

Comment: You need to provide a working fiddle; I suspect you're adding the `hide_menu` class and never removing it, which may be causing your issue (as well as the way you're selecting everything over and over). I don't know, though, *because I can't **see** it in practice*.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mvMJ5/1/

Comment: You posted a non-working fiddle.

Comment: The fact that you are using a `.menu` class **&** a `<menu>` tag confuses us. In your css, you use `menu li`, but there are no li in your _<menu>_ tag...

Comment: sorry first time used js fiddle :) http://jsfiddle.net/mvMJ5/2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mvMJ5/3/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mvMJ5/4/

Comment: @jared , @ blex you both gave my good solutions and i appreciate your time.. if you would like to put an answer in i will tick your answer +1 vote for you aswell thank you again

Comment: dont understand the down votes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the event binding `$("menu").mouseleave()` outside.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7Uc72/

Comment: yeah, its cleaner but same result, it works once..shows the menu then when mouse leaves it hides the menu but i cant show the menu a second time unless if i refresh the page.